# How can I make this json format from php?

Tags: php, mysql, json

Hi to all developers

I have the below json format

```
[
  {
    "name": "typeahead.js",
    "description": "A fast and fully-featured autocomplete library",
    "language": "JavaScript",
    "value": "typeahead.js",
    "tokens": [
      "typeahead.js",
      "JavaScript"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "cassandra",
    "description": "A Ruby client for the Cassandra distributed database",
    "language": "Ruby",
    "value": "cassandra",
    "tokens": [
      "cassandra",
      "Ruby"
    ]
  },
]
```

I made a mysql table called **testable** with these columns

**Id, name, description, language, value, tokens**

and I am trying to produce the above format of json file through **php** and **testable**.

Can you suggest me an approach on this?

Comment: Have you looked at `json_encode()` yet? http://www.php.net/json_encode

Comment: How is the data in "tokens" column of your DB being stored? This would seem to be a join table of some sort, rather than a single value?

Comment: Yes I have tried json_encode() but I am getting a different format than what I describe in the beginning of the question. I am getting a json format in a row but it not what I want

Comment: Associative array output as objects

{"foo":"bar","baz":"long"}

is the same as

{
  "foo":"bar",
  "baz":"long"
}

Comment: Head over to [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/), paste your code and hit Validate, it will prettify it for you. There is no reason to send more bytes over the wire than absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2):

For this example I will assume you use `MySQLi`. I will also assume you're storing tokens as separated values, since you do not mention anything about a second table.

```
$db = new Mysqli(<your credentials>);
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM testable");

$arr = array();
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    $tokens = explode('<separator>', $row['tokens']);
    $row['tokens'] = $tokens;

    $arr[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: I think this one works - Depending on how you're storing your tokens (why I mentioned the join table above), you can explode them in this manner. One gotcha in json converting is that if you are working with floats or ints, make sure to cast them explicitly when creating your array or jason_encode() will stringify them.. So, if(isset($row['myfloat'])) { $row['myfloat'] = (float)$row['myfloat'] } etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
define('DB_HOST', 'Your db host here');
define('DB_NAME', 'Your db name here');
define('DB_USER', 'Your db user here');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'Your db password here');
$connectionString = 'mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';database=' . DB_NAME;
$pdo = new PDO($connectionString, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
$sql = "SELECT name, description, language, value, tokens FROM testable";
// Prepared statement now b/c it's a better default.
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject())
{
    $results[] = $row;
    $results[count($results) - 1]->tokens = blackMagic($row->tokens); //Need to see how tokens are stored to do the blackMagic function.
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

Comment: Thank for answer jameslafferty.I have already created the table.My problem is how to produce the mentioned json file from my table with the help of php.Could you help me on that?

Comment: Updated it... sorry, I misunderstood your question at first, I think.

Answer (score 0):

We need to form an array, to get the above JSON format.

The array is as below :

```
<?php
  $array = array (
             0 => array (
                    'name' => 'typeahead.js',
                    'description' => 'A fast and fully-featured autocomplete library',
                    'language' => 'JavaScript',
                    'value' => 'typeahead.js',
                    'tokens' => array (
                                   0 => 'typeahead.js',
                                   1 => 'JavaScript',
                                ),
                  ),
             1 => array (
                    'name' => 'cassandra',
                    'description' => 'A Ruby client for the Cassandra distributed database',
                    'language' => 'Ruby',
                    'value' => 'cassandra',
                    'tokens' => array (
                                   0 => 'cassandra',
                                   1 => 'Ruby',
                                ),
                     ),
      ); 
  echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Comment: I think it's question is how to make it from the database, not how to make json from an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
// fetch data from the table
$query = $dbcon->query("SELECT * FROM testable");

// form an array 
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    $arr = array();
    $arr["name"] = $row["name"];
    $arr["description"] = $row["description"];
    $arr["language"] = $row["language"];
    //... add more data here according to your records...


    $data[] = $arr;
}


// $data will be formed as :
/*    
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => typeahead.js
            [description] => A fast and fully-featured autocomplete library
            [language] => JavaScript
            [value] => typeahead.js
            [tokens] => Array
                (
                    [0] => typeahead.js
                    [1] => JavaScript
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => cassandra
            [description] => A Ruby client for the Cassandra distributed database
            [language] => Ruby
            [value] => cassandra
            [tokens] => Array
                (
                    [0] => cassandra
                    [1] => Ruby
                )

        )

)

*/  

// then 
echo json_encode($data);


// output

[
    {
        "name":"typeahead.js",
        "description":"A fast and fully-featured autocomplete library",
        "language":"JavaScript",
        "value":"typeahead.js",
        "tokens":["typeahead.js","JavaScript"]
    },

    {
        "name":"cassandra",
        "description":"A Ruby client for the Cassandra distributed database",
        "language":"Ruby",
        "value":"cassandra",
        "tokens":["cassandra","Ruby"]
    }
]
```